# How to correctly get current loop count from a Iterator in scala

Tags: scala

I am looping over the following lines from a csv file to parse them.  I want to identify the first line since its the header.  Whats the best way of doing this instead of making a var counter holder.

```
var counter = 0
for (line <- lines) {
  println(CsvParser.parse(line, counter))
  counter++
}
```

I know there is got to be a better way to do this, newbie to Scala.

Comment: You could possibly use a foldLeft for that, not ideal, but I haven't seen a foreachWithIndex in any collection.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try `zipWithIndex`:

```
for (line <- lines.zipWithIndex) {
  println(CsvParser.parse(line._1, line._2))
}
```

[@tenshi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/576766]) suggested the following improvement with pattern matching:

```
for ((line, count) <- lines.zipWithIndex) {
  println(CsvParser.parse(line, count))
}
```

Comment: I find, that in this case, it would be also nice to use pattern matching: `for ((line, count) <- lines.zipWithIndex) { println(CsvParser.parse(line, count)) }`

Comment: @tenshi: I added your suggestion to my answer, hope you don't mind.

Comment: Or: `lines.zipWithIndex foreach Function.tupled(CsvParser.parse)`.

Answer (score 7):

I totally agree with the given answer, still that I've to point something important out and initially I planned to put in a simple comment.

But it would be quite long, so that, leave me set it as a variant answer.

It's prefectly true that `zip*` methods are helpful in order to create tables with lists, but they have the counterpart that they loop the lists in order to create it.

So that, a common recommendation is to sequence the actions required on the lists in a `view`, so that you combine all of them to be applied only producing a result will be required. Producing a result is considered when the returnable isn't an `Iterable`. So is `foreach` for instance.

Now, talking about the first answer, if you have `lines` to be the list of lines in a very big file (or even an enumeratee on it), `zipWithIndex` will go through all of 'em and produce a table (Iterable of tuples). Then the for-comprehension will go back again through the same amount of items.

Finally, you've impacted the running lenght by `n`, where `n` is the length of `lines` and added a memory footprint of `m + n*16` (roughtly) where `m` is the `lines`' footprint.

### Proposition

```
lines.view.zipWithIndex map Function.tupled(CsvParser.parse) foreach println
```

Some few words left (I promise), `lines.view` will create something like `scala.collection.SeqView` that will hold all further "mapping" function producing new Iterable, as are `zipWithIndex` and `map`.

Moreover, I think the expression is more elegant because it follows the reader and logical.
"For **lines**, create a **view** that will **zip each** item with its **index**, the result as to be **mapped** on the result of the **parser** which must be **printed**".

HTH.

Comment: I tried your solution but I get the error: view is not a member of Iterator[String]  my lines are produced by val lines = fromFile("runners/io/m2m/naf/ARDS.csv").getLines

Comment: You can drop the "view" from your proposition. Since `lines` is already an iterator, it works almost as view - maps, filters, etc are all put on hold until elements are requested from it.

Comment: Mmmmh ok, I don't know your use case. But I recommanda you to have an Iterable instead. Or use foldLeft and use à Thomson where you retain the count. So that you'll be able to do all your stuff at once.  I' ll update the answer with that option.